# How can I open application using C# from port 9999

Tags: c#, sockets, port

i want to open application using c# code . application needs to be open at port number 9999 . i don't know how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by open? Do you mean you want to open the port in a firewall? Or do you want to listen to network communication on that port using C#? Or do you want to open the application and change which ports it's using internally?

Comment: i want to open that application and then want to send some command to that application .

Comment: Best would be to implement RPC using WCF. You question is much, much too vague by the way.

Comment: Is it your application? Should the application react to what you are writing?

Comment: what's the application? couldn't you use a shell script for that?

Comment: arguably **too broad** with a touch of **unclear what you're asking**. _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Congratulations for being extremely vague.

Comment: yes , application will react.

Comment: just need code to open that application on specific port

Comment: If you want _"activation"_ I would have thought _WCF; .NET Remoting or DCOM_ would be required, not just plain TCP.  TCP won't automatically run/activate an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
  private void SendToServer(IPAddress IP, int Port) {
        try {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            tcpclnt.Connect(IP, Port);
            //your code here
            }
```

> UPDATE
>   For the server you'll use this

```
public static void Main() {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(9999);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;
            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started");
            counter = 0;
            while (true) {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");
                handleClient client = new handleClient();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class handleClient {
//yourcodehere
}
```

[Source](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm)

Comment: Could the person who downvoted please explain the downvote?
The question is vague however this will open the port.

Comment: I take it back apparently you guessed right

Comment: I suspect it is because it does not address _"i want to **open that application** and then want to send some command to that application"_.  Your answer appears to only address the later.  TCP won't magically activate an app.  .NET Remoting/WCF would

Comment: ok. i will try thanks.

Comment: ah I see, My answer is then irrelevant.

Been working with creating server client applications recently so I thought I'd weigh in.

My thoughts would be to use telnet. 

Unless he pre-coded the application to use port 9999 and then opened it via another application